# c# release folder identical to debug folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I made a simple little app that pretty much is only an embedded chromium thing displaying an included html file. It works perfectly fine, but when I switch over to release mode and build, the release folder has 30ish files, and the main exe throws an error if I delete any files.

I'm pretty sure all the extra files are related to cefsharp, is there any way to produce a single exe using it?

[release folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QXJr.png)

Comment: You can embed the dependencies as resources and extract them at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an IE web control, it depends on components included with Windows so you don't need to distribute anything.

Chromium applications depend on your program providing the full set of files for the chromium widget - DLLs, locale and pak files, etc. - because none of those are distributed by Microsoft as part of Windows or .NET.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, is there any way to bundle the files into the exe, or do I still have to distribute the whole folder?

Comment: For Chromium apps, you need it all and they can't be statically linked into your EXE.  So to distribute you'll need to zip or use an installer.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I just made a hidden window self extracting archive with winrar to make a 'portable' version of the normal app